# How to disable windows beep sound on delete key press

Tags: java, swing

I have a java swing application that beeps everytime I delete a row in a jtable.

Anyone have any ideas how I can prevent this from happening or at least what is causing this?

Comment: Please add the code so we all can review it.

Answer (score 1):

From here: https://www.java.net/node/687490

> On Windows, pressing the Alt key moves the keyboard focus to the
>   window menu in the top left corner. This focus is invisible, and it
>   even does not send a "focus lost" event. But if you press and release
>   Alt and then press the up or down arrow, the window menu will show up.
>
> Luckily, it's possible to prevent this functionality of the Alt key:

```
 addKeyListener( new KeyAdapter() { 
   public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) { 
      System.out.println("keyPressed code=" + e.getKeyCode()); 
      e.consume(); 
 } } );
```

> e.consume( ) prevents the event to be processed by usual rules. This
>   prevents the Alt key from moving the focus to the window menu, and
>   further alphanumeric keys continue to function as usual. You may want
>   to check the event code and consume only Alt keys, if something else
>   stops working.